# Load Teamcity build log from step

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I need to load TeamCity build log from step(command line runner or another) to file.
And I need to do it from build step. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to output the build log of a specific build step to a file?

Comment: My guess is that he wants to perform some custom metrics on his build. I'm attempting to do the same. The answer to this question looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use Teamcity api to get log using wget or some other tool

```
http://teamcity.server/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=NNNN
```

[TeamCity Api](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API)